# Showing Big base64 pdf files in chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, pdf, base64

I'm working on an email like working web app and in one form, I must show pdf files that got from server in base64 form to the user, for small files, for example, smaller than 2 megabytes, there is no problem, chrome shows the file successfully but for bigger files, it just shows me a blank screen.

and this problem only occurs in chrome, in firefox it's normal. 
I haven't tested all browsers! :)

my code is something like this

```
dataService.getPagedData(datasourceUrl).then(function (data) {
    var url = "data:application/pdf;base64," + data;
    element.replaceWith('<object id="pdfdoc" style="width:100%" type="application/pdf" data="' + varUrl + '" height="' + varHeight + '"></object>');
});
```

Comment: The data url scheme originally has originally only been specified for small files, up to a few KB. Browsers implemented them for somewhat larger files and people used then for larger files. Nonetheless, that is usage beyond the specification and its support is up to the specific implementation in each browser.